# AngularJS : TypeError: $http(...).success is not a function on asp.net WebMethod

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-1.6

I am new to `AngularJs` and using it in a web form

My Code is as below

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', [])
app.controller('usrController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.userdata = {};
    var post = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "Index.aspx/GetData",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.userdata = data.d;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        $window.alert(data.Message);
    });
});
```

My WebMethod code is as below

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = Helper.UserList("sp_GetSearchList");
    string JSONString = string.Empty;
    JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt).ToString();
    return JSONString;
}
```

My JSONString returns perfect json but I got error as

> TypeError: $http(...).success is not a function

I have seen a lot of answers on Stack overflow but none of them actually solved this.

### Extended Question

After using the following code it solved my question

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', [])
app.controller('usrController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.userdata = {};
    $http.post("Index.aspx/GetData", {}).
    then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response.data.d));
        $scope.userdata = JSON.parse(response.data.d);
    });
}, 
function(error) {

});
```

My front end binding is this

```
<body data-ng-app="demoApp">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div data-ng-controller="usrController">
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Sl No</th>
                     <th>User ID</th>
                     <th>Employee ID</th>
                     <th>Employee Name</th>
                     <th>Birth Date</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr data-ng-repeat="data in userdata">
                    <td>{{data.ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.UserID}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.EmployeeID}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.EmpName}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.BirthDate}}</td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The data comes perfectly in `console.log` but its not binding in front end.

Help me where I am wrong.Thanks in advance

Comment: Try use `then` function instead of `success` function because it has expired.

Comment: Thanks now its coming in `data.d` but how to use the `error`

Comment: show `userdata`  object structure.

Comment: I returned a `datatable` and convert it to` json` so I have no user class. See the `GetData()` Method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this

```
 $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "Index.aspx/GetData",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
}).then(function(result) {
  //Success
 }, function(error) {
 //Error
 });
```

Comment: This works perfectly and returns data in console in json format
 `console.log(JSON.parse(response.data.d));
        $scope.userdata = JSON.parse(response.data.d);`
But I am not able to bind this in front end

Comment: share what you tried to bind it or ask new question.

Comment: I changed my question please check

Answer (score 5):

In **Angular 1.6**, the `$http` service has changed: you can't use `.success` and `.error` anymore.

Instead, use `.then`. From [`$http` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below.

```
 $http.post( "Index.aspx/GetData", {} )
   .then(function(response) {
      $scope.userdata = response.data;
   });
```

Comment: More than two years later and your answer saved my bacon. Thank you, sir.